# Getting grey screen for excel workbooks opened/created by macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting grey screen when I manually try to open excel workbooks created/opened in a macro. I'm using normal methods for `open`, `save` and `close` but still unable to figure out why this is happening. Below are the code snippets from my macro: 
Create

```
 Set resultWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
 resultWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.result_folder & "\" & job_group_name & ".xlsx"
 resultWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
```

After writing

```
resultWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Before Closing Macro

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.Visible = False
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the workbook you are saving have any macros in it?

Comment: @braX No, it doesn't have. Simple xlsx.

Comment: change this : `resultWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True`

Comment: @SharifLotfi I want it to be hidden. Can I make it visible just before closing to avoid the issue?

Comment: When I open a workbook and that happens it means a macro didn't enable the `screenupdating` again, would it be possible to be your problem? (resolves by closing all your workbooks or enbaling it on the vba)

Comment: @Damian Let me try this. So, `screenupdating` property is specific for workbooks?

Comment: No, it's application's. So if you disabled and never enabled it back, all the workbooks you open from there on manually will be grey @AbhinavKushagra.

Comment: @Damian that's right.

Comment: @Damian If it's application's then it should've happened with all the workbooks but It's happening only with the workbooks which I'm saving and closing using the macro.

Comment: @Damian Tried setting `Application.ScreenUpdating` property to `True` still the same issue :(

Comment: This line `resultWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False` hides the window and it will stay hidden unless you unhide it. You can unhide the windows either manually or with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you saved your files with `resultWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False` you hid the window. The window will stay hidden when you open the file. That's the reason you get a grey screen. You can either unhide the window manually as described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hide-or-show-worksheets-or-workbooks-69f2701a-21f5-4186-87d7-341a8cf53344) in the section **Hide or unhide a workbook window** or you add an event to you Excel which fires whenever you open a file and unhides it. Code for that could look like that

```
Option Explicit
Dim WithEvents xlApp As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set xlApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Wb.Windows(1).Visible = True
End Sub
```

You have to add that to `ThisWorkbook` of another macro enabled file which you open when you start excel.

Or you add the line `resultWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True` just before you save and close the file

```
resultWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
resultWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```